# getting through multiple pages in web scraping

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I am working on web scraping, to get values from yello pages and while iterating through pages  the loop function isnt getting the page count increment. I have added a loop its keep on showing data from same page. i am attaching my code below.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string webUrl = "https://www.yellowpages.com";
        bool Loop = true;
        HtmlWeb Web = new HtmlWeb();

        //First Url
        HtmlDocument doc = Web.Load(webUrl + "/search?search_terms=software&geo_location_terms=Los+Angeles%2C+CA");
        var HeaderName = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@class='business-name']").ToList();
        foreach (var abc in HeaderName)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(abc.InnerText);
        }

        //Loop through different pages from the paging of that first url and then keep on doing it until Next button returns nothing
        while (Loop == true)
        {
            var NextPageCheck = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[text()='Next']/@href").ToList();
            if (NextPageCheck.Count != 0)
            {
                string link = webUrl + NextPageCheck[0].Attributes["href"].Value;
                doc = Web.Load(link);
                HeaderName = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@class='business-name']").ToList();

                foreach (var abc in HeaderName)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(abc.InnerText);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Loop = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

So the issue i am facing is, it keeps on showing the result from 2nd page. i want it to iterate that page and till there is no page number left like if it has 400 pages(in total), it should take that page url to 400 
https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=software&geo_location_terms=Los%20Angeles%2C%20CA&page=2
**page=2**

Comment: So what is your actual question? I cannot find any question in your initial post... Do you get any errors? Is it not working as intended?

Comment: **I have added a loop its keep on showing data from same page.**

It keep on showing the result from 2 page. i want it to iterate that page and till there is no page number left like if it has 400 pages it should take that page url to 400.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst debugging your code it seems I was getting a null error on the line in which you looking for the business names the second time around, in the version of HtmlAgilityPack that  had installed it was encoding the urls so I simply added a decoding to the url

```
string link = webUrl + NextPageCheck[0].Attributes["href"].Value;
var urlDecode = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(link);
doc = Web.Load(urlDecode);
```

And it seemed to work fine - as the comment says next time you post it would be helpful to post the error you are getting and what line so it's easier and faster to track down the actual bug

Hope this helps.

Comment: It worked, thanks.
and referring to your suggestions, I will keep that in mind next time.